# Is a single string enough to prove regular expressions inequivalent?

Tags: formal-languages, proof-techniques, regular-expressions

> Which of the following regular expressions generate a language that is different from the rest?
>
> 1. (a+b)$^*$a(a+b)$^*$(a+b)$^*$
> 2. b$^*$ab$^*$a(a+b)$^*$
> 3. (a+b)$^*$ab$^*$ab$^*$
> 4. b$^*$ a(a+b)$^*$ab$^*$

RE 1 generates a language that contains the string 'a' which no other language among 2,3,4 contains, so can I say this language is different from all others?  Does it suffice to show that a single string is not present in the language and hence its different from the rest?

Comment: yes its called a *proof by counter-example* QED

Answer (score 8):

> Does it suffice to show that a single string is not present in the language and hence its different from the rest?

Yes. It's actually a very neat proof.

Formally speaking, you have found $w \in \{a,b\}^*$ with $w \in L_1$ but $w \not\in L_2,L_3,L_4$. That is sufficient to show that $L_1 \neq L_2$, $L_1 \neq L_3$ and $L_1 \neq L_4$.

You have *not* shown that $L_2 = L_3 = L_4$. The phrasing of the question seems to suggest as much (MC questions are *boring*!) but you may want to prove that as an additional exercise.

> *Hint:* Translate into NFA, determinize, minimize, check for isomorphy.

Comment: The procedure given in the hint seems overkill. `abaa` is accepted by L2 not L4 so they're not equivalent either.

Comment: @MSalters All four regular expressions match `abaa`. Maybe it's not overkill after all? (I honestly do not not a more efficient way to establish equivalence of regular expressions *formally*.)

Comment: I might overlook something, but L4 is `b* a (a+b)* ab*`, so 4 parts. Matching `abaa` we see that the leading `b*` occurs zero times, the 2nd term produces the first `a` in `abaa` leaving `baa`, the third term produces the one `b` leaving `aa` and the final `ab*` does NOT produces `aa`. It can produce at most a single `a`.

Comment: @MSalters $ba \in L((a+b)^*)$, so you go $a \in L(a)$, then $ba \in L((a+b)^*)$, and then $a \in L(ab^*)$ to get $abaa$.

Comment: The three remaining all sprecify strings that have at least two $a$'s? The expressions "focus" on the first two, the last two and the outer two $a$'s respectively.

Comment: @G.Bach: I don't think so. `(a+b)` means "mandatory b, optionally preceded by at least one a". `(a+b)*` is zero or more repetitions of that whole group. In words: "zero or more b's, each **preceded** by a number of a's". In `ba`, the last `a` **follows** the `b`.

Comment: @MSalters No, that's typically not what $(a + b)$ (or $(a \mid b)$) means. Note that it does not seem to say $(a^+ b)$ -- that's a different thing! G.Bach has given a correct answer. Please check the definition of regular expressions again if you don't follow him.

Comment: I think the question is ambiguous. In programming languages `a+b` means `aa*b`. In theoretical contexts `a+b` means `[ab]` (in programming syntax).

Comment: @Buge Since this site is about computer science and not programming, hence about regular expressions and not regexps, I'd say it's pretty clear how to read it. (Some authors never use $^+$ since it's so easily simulated.)

Answer (score 5):

A language is just a set of strings. To show that sets $X$ and $Y$ are different, it's always enough to show that $X$ contains something that's not in $Y$ or vice-versa. This is because two sets are defined to be equal exactly if they have the same elements.

Comment: I was tempted to write "the symmetric difference is not empty" but I figured that was more likely to add salt to the wound. :D